# Android & iOS access number dialing

Tags: android, ios, phone-call

I am very new to both these operating systems.

We are planning a secure dialing system which means dialing two numbers in one phone number dialing session.

Currently we have a system which allows us to dial an access number, wait for a tone and then dial a full telephone number.

It's a bit elaborate but, like I said, it's a security feature.

What we are now trying to do is create Android and iPhone apps that will allow us to dial the access number + telephone number at the click of a virtual button.

How this can be accomplished programmatically? I need to implement something like "access-number#phone-number" or anything that works.

Answer (score 2):

Both iphone and android support making phone calls in the same sort of manner.

You need to construct a URL and 'run' the url.  Both iphone and android don't support any sort of call control so you have to make do with the url to make a phone call.   They both support 'pause' character and dtmf tones in the url.

The iphone don't support some characters, notably the '#' and '*' characters.  Because the '#' character is not supported (for security reasons), it can make it hard dealing with PBX systems.

On the android you have to 'encode' characters manually or using URLEncoder.  I have not had any luck supporting the '#' character in Android but I have seen reports of it working. You will need to test this to see if it works for you.

For iphone you use the [UIApplication openURL:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728) to a [tel link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1).

e.g.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456p12345"]];
```

For android you use the [INTENT_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) or [ACTION_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL).

INTENT_CALL will display the phone dialler with you number filled out.  It does not require any special setup.

e.g.

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:123456"));
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

ACTION_CALL requires the [CALL_PHONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE) permission in your manifest file.
e.g.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123456%2C12345"));
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for but.

You could create a button in your layout.
Create a pointer to it in your main activity // findViewById();

OnClickListener on the Button.

in the onClick, fire a Dial Intent with the number of choice.

If this isn't what you're looking for I'm afraid I'll need a bit more information on what it truely is, because at this point that's the only thing I can manage to think of with the description given.

Comment: Thanks Androider. The issue is not just dialing one number. It's dialing the number and inputing a passcode simultaneously in a single programmatic Android dailing action.